# JsRender how to render object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I have this object:

```
App.estados = {
    'AC':'Acre',
    'AL':'Alagoas',
    'AM':'Amazonas',
    'AP':'Amapá',
    'BA':'Bahia',...
};
```

and I'm trying to load it in a template:

```
$.templates ({
    address: '{{include tmpl="begin" /}}' +
             '{{props \'App.estados\'}}' +
             '<option value="{{>key}}">{{>prop}}</option> ' +
             '{{/props}}' +
             '{{include tmpl="end" /}}'
});
```

to get this:

```
<option value="AC">Acre</option>
...
```

Why this is not working? I already tried to create a helper with Ap.estados, but didn't work too.

Thank you,

Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/243.

BTW in general it is not necessary to ask both on GitHub and here in Stack Overflow. GitHub issues (https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues) is especially for bug reports. Here is fine for questions about how to use JsRender.

But before either of those it is a good plan to check the docs and samples here: http://www.jsviews.com/...